# validation for alphabets forward slash and dot

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

am trying to validate relation field which will have alphabets, forward slash and dot for e.g
(s/o. Mr.ram or w/o. Mr.ram), i have already tried this ([a-z])/([a-z]) but it is not working
please help am new to this 
thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly should be matched? Apart from the need to escape `/`, your expression would match only a three-character string consisting of a lowercase letter, a slash, and a lowercase letter. This is hardly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested this in the JS console, you need to escape the slash in regular expressions.

```
 /([a-z])\/([a-z])/
```

Should do it for you.

[image: Examples below]

Comment: i need some pattern which should accept like this  s/o. Mr.ram

Comment: I've attached an image showing the results from the console. Works just fine for me.